# Loop trough an array and compare two values from the lowest to the highest value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want loop trough an array and compare two values which are next to each other, but not after the index like this:

```
for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) { 
  if (arr[i]-arr[i-1] == 10) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Because when the array looks like this:

```
10, -20, 20, 50
```

It will compare (I start with "1" in the loop) **-20** with **20**, and **20** with **50**.

What I want is to compare the array like **-20** with **10**, **10** with **20** and **20** with **50**. Also from the lowest to the highest value and then use

```
if (arr[i]-arr[i-1] == 10)
```

Comment: So, just `sort` it first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would make sense to sort your array first using the built in array.sort method.

```
let sortedArr = arr.sort((a, b) => (a - b))
```

This will put your array in ascending order (lowest to highest), allowing you to do your comparison more cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is use [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) like so:

```js
var arr = [10, -20, 20, 50];
var sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => a > b);
console.log(arr);
console.log(sorted);
```

Then you can use your logic on it:

```js
var arr = [10, -20, 20, 50];
var sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => a > b);
for (var i = 1; i < sorted.length; i++) {
    if (sorted[i] - sorted[i - 1] == 10) {
        console.log("Do something");
    }
}
```